# How to catch ScrollToPosition event in a CFormView?

Tags: c++, mfc, vertical-scrolling

I'm implementing a vertical scrolling mechanism using `OnVScroll`.
Some buttons in my dialog call `ScrollToPosition ()` function. The particularity of this function is that it changes the configuration of the scroll bar **without** notifying `OnVScroll`. This makes my job a lot more complicated.

**Question :**
How can I catch `ScrollToPosition ()` event ?

**Environment details:**

- Windows 7
- Visual studio 2010
- MFC

Answer (score 0):

Why not override the `ScrollToPosition` method in **your** `CFormView` class?

```
void CMyView::ScrollToPosition( POINT pt )
{
    // Do something

    // Call base class
    CFormView::ScrollToPosition( pt );
}
```

Comment: @AndrewTrukle thanks. but what i must add in BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP part ? For example : for *OnVScroll* i add *ON_WM_VSCROLL()*

Comment: @Alpha_33 You are overriding a method and then calling the base implementation. This is not a "message" so you do not need an entry in the message map.

Comment: i add it, i'm not fire on on this function i don't know why

Comment: @Alpha_33 Can you please provide us with a test project that we can use to reproduce your issue? Please add a link to it to your question.

Comment: i will try to isolate the problem because i have a very big project

Comment: @Alpha_33 The only thing I can think of is that `ScrollToPosition` is not `virtual`. Maybe that is the reason, in which case someone else might have advice. But a working sample we can try would be useful.

Comment: I try to declare the function as `virtual`, the breakpoint is not reached

Comment: You can’t just declare it yourself. The base function has to be declared that way. That is out of your hands.

Comment: I found a solution by adding a custom sendmessage just after calling ScrollToPosition